# VBA search replace text in word document from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make an excel document that I can paste a list of words to search and replace into.  I want to use the excel document to search and replace these words in a word document.

I am having issues getting the code to function.

```
Sub SearchReplace()

Dim WordDoc As Object, N As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
i = Range("C2").Value  'pulls length of list from an excel function located in cell C2
N = Range("B4:C" & CStr(i + 3)).Value
Set WordDoc = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    WordDoc.Visible = True
WordDoc.Documents.Open Filename:="C:\WordTest.docm"
WordDoc.Activate
With WordDoc.ActiveDocument
    For j = 1 To i
    With .Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = N(1, j)
            .Replacement.Text = N(2, j)
            .Execute
         End With
    End With
    Next j
End With
WordDoc.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

I corrected the code based on the recommendations, and I no longer get any errors.  However the code does not appear to find and replace anything in the specified word document.  I tried to simplify the code to check the find & replace portion by typing in a specific word "text" and a specific word "replace" to find and replace in a word document, which contains the word "text".  This still result in no change. I removed the line that closed the document in case the issue was the document was not being saved after being updated, but that also was not successful, so I added WordDoc.Quit back into the code.

```
Sub SearchReplace()

Dim WordDoc As Object, N As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

i = Range("C2").Value  'pulls length of list from an excel function 
located in cell C2
N = Range("B4:C" & CStr(i + 3)).Value
Set WordDoc = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
WordDoc.Visible = True
WordDoc.Documents.Open Filename:="C:\WordTest.docm"
WordDoc.Documents("WordTest.docm").Activate
With WordDoc.ActiveDocument
For j = 1 To i
With .Range
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = 1
        .Text = "text" 'N(j, 1)
        .Replacement.Text = "replace" 'N(j, 2)
        .Execute 2
     End With
End With
Next j
End With
WordDoc.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you get the first error message when you run the code and what is says?

Comment: Please describe in the issues in detail. We can't possibly reproduce your situation and problems based on the minimal information you provide.

Comment: Unless you've added a reference to the Word object library, Excel isn't going to know what the value of `wdFindContinue` is.  You'll need to either add the reference, or define that constant.  And use `Option Explicit` so you always know about this type of problem.

Comment: I think you have your column and row indexes transposed.  It should be N(j,1) and N(j,2).

Comment: Once I included Option Explicit I received an error on  .Wrap=wdFindContinue.  I do not understand how to define this in excel, would you please explain.

Comment: Yes N(j,1) and N(j,2) were transposed, thank you but the error for wdFindContinue is still receiving an error.  Compile error:  Variable not defined.

Comment: Word.WdFind.WdFindContinue

Comment: Ooops, a slip of the mouse.  Your simplest option is to add the reference to the word object model by using Tools.References and ticking the box against the Microsoft Word XX.X Object library. If you still get errors then you will have to qualify your constants e.g. Word.WdFind.wdFindContinue.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the code to function.  The code searches a specified Microsoft Word Document from Excel using a list of find replace strings from the excel sheet (B4:B5004 (find), C4:C5005 (replace)) stored in an array in the code.

To get the code to function I had to include the Microsoft Word 16 Object Library.

From the excel VBA editor window. 
Tools > References  then ensure Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library is checked.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchReplace()

   Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, N As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
   i = Range("C2").Value  'pulls length of list from an excel function located in cell C2 =COUNTIF(B4:B5005,"*")
   N = Range("B4:C" & CStr(i + 3)).Value
   Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
   Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\WordTest.docm")    
   WordDoc.Visible = True
   For j = 1 To i
        With WordApp
           With WordDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = N(j, 1)
                .Replacement.Text = N(j, 2)
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
          End With
        End With
    Next j
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Save
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: this saved me, thanks! I couldn't find why isn't replacing anything. Adding the reference worked just as expected at first place.

Answer (score 1):

The "Compile error: Variable not defined" problem is due to your use of late binding with a named Word constant. Either change

```
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
```

to:

```
.Wrap =  1
```

or insert:

```
Const wdFindContinue as Long = 1
```

at the top of your code.

In any event, as it stands, your existing code won't replace anything. Instead of:

```
.Execute
```

you need either:

```
.Execute 2
```

or:

```
.Execute wdReplaceAll
```

(to replace all instances) or:

```
.Execute 1
```

or:

```
.Execute wdReplaceOne
```

(to replace only the first instance)

As with wdFindContinue, you'd need to supplement wdReplaceAll or wdReplaceOne with:

```
Const wdReplaceAll as Long = 2
```

or:

```
Const wdReplaceOne as Long = 1
```

as appropriate.

Comment: I made the adjustment and it runs without any errors.  However it does not seem to find and replace any text.  I tried adjusted the code to test it by simply entering in what to find and what to replace it with "Text" and "Changed" and added these words to the word document.  It can't seem to find them and change them.    I changed .Wrap=1 and .Execute 2

Comment: (comment removed)

Comment: How about posting your modified code so we can see what you're actually using?

Comment: Updated in the original post.

Comment: Since you don't save the changes before quitting, you're unlikely to ever see what the find/replace did.